# Set Inequality Proof Check

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Looking at a problem on an intro. analysis practice exam:
Prove that

$$ U\setminus(A\setminus B)\ \;=\; (U\setminus A)\setminus B $$

I don't think this is true, here is the counterexample that I cooked up:
$$ U\;=\;\{1,2,3,\dots, 9, 10\}$$
$$ A\;=\;\{2,4,6,8\} $$
$$ B\;=\; \{2,4,5,7\} $$
Considering $u=2$, we have $u\in \{1,2,3,4,5,7,9,10\}=U\setminus(A\setminus B)$, yet $u\notin \{1,3,9,10\}=(U\setminus A)\setminus B$.

Just looking for a quick verification, seeing as the awkward scenario here is an undergraduate is claiming that a tenured professor is incorrect (maybe he did it on purpose?).

Comment: You are correct. More generally, if $x\in U\cap A\cap B$, then $x\in U\setminus(A\setminus B)$, but $x\notin(U\setminus A)\setminus B$.

Comment: The easiest counterexample is probably $U=A=B=\{1\}$.

Comment: It's probably a typo, and meant to be $U \setminus ( A \cup B ) = (U \setminus A) \setminus B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prove it is not valid through the properties of the operators involved.

Here I assume that $U$ is the universe of discourse.

On one hand, we have that

\begin{align*}
U - (A - B) & = U - (A\cap B^{c})\\\\
& = U\cap(A\cap B^{c})^{c}\\\\
& = U\cap (A^{c}\cup B)\\\\
& = A^{c}\cup B
\end{align*}

On the other hand, we have that

\begin{align*}
(U - A) - B & = (U\cap A^{c}) - B\\\\
& = (U\cap A^{c})\cap B^{c}\\\\
& = U\cap (A^{c}\cap B^{c})\\\\
& = A^{c}\cap B^{c}
\end{align*}

In general, $A^{c}\cup B \neq A^{c}\cap B^{c}$.

Hopefully this helps!